# How to right-click in Netbeans 'Customize Layout' uppon a group of selected components (on a Mac)

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I have selected two components in the Customize Layout screen using a hint from a stackoverflow user (ctrl + alt + click) but it seems that right-clicking is not operational when you have selected more than one component.
Is there any key combination to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

PS : I am using Netbeans 7.1.2

PS2 : My operating system is MAC OS Lion (10.7.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following works on NB + Mac:

1. select the first component
2. hold ctrl + alt + cmd and click the other component (ctrl + alt causes the second one to be selected without deselecting the first one and cmd causes the pop-up menu to appear - i.e. right-click)

Comment: Another way to achieve this is using the Navigator window.I should have thought that at the first place!